# delete element BST

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers

When I delete 25 from BT than it works perfectly.
But when I want to delete another number like 17,
it deletes 17 with some other number are deleted from BT.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{

    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

node *root = NULL;

node* createnode(int data)
{

    node *t = new node();
    t->data = data;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    return t;

}

node* min(node*);

node* insert(node *root, int data)
{

    if (root == NULL)
    {


        root = createnode(data);
        return root;
    }

    else{

        node *t = root;
        if (data <= t->data)
            t->left = insert(t->left, data);
        else{
            t->right = insert(t->right, data);
        }
    }
}

node* print(node *root)
{

    if (root == NULL)
    {

        return root;
    }

    else{

        cout << root->data << " ";
        print(root->left);
        print(root->right);
    }

    return root;
}

node* deleten(node *root, int data)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    else{
        if (data<root->data)
            root->left = deleten(root->left, data);
        if (data>root->data)
            root->right = deleten(root->right, data);
        else{
            if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            {
                node *t = root;
                root = NULL;
                delete t;
            }
            else if (root->left == NULL)
            {
                node *t = root;
                root = root->right;
                delete t;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL)
            {
                node *t = root;
                root = root->left;
                delete t;
            }
            else{
                node *t = min(root->right);
                root->data = t->data;
                root->right = deleten(root->right, t->data);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
}

node* min(node *root)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    else{
        if (root->left != NULL)
            min(root->left);
        else{
            return root;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    root = insert(root, 15);
    root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 8);
    root = insert(root, 12);
    root = insert(root, 11);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 23);
    root = insert(root, 17);
    root = insert(root, 25);
    root = print(root);
    cout << endl;
    root = deleten(root, 17);
    root = print(root);
}
```

case 1:

before deletion : 15 10 8 12 11 20 17 23 25

after  deletion : 15 10 8 12 11 23 25 // root=deleten(root,17);

expectation         :    15 10 8 12 11 20 23 25

case 2:

before deletion : 15 10 8 12 11 20 17 23 25

after  deletion : 15 10 8 12 11 20 17 23 // root=deleten(root,25);

expectation      : 15 10 8 12 11 20 17 23

case 3:

before deletion : 15 10 8 12 11 20 17 23 25

after  deletion  : 17 12 11 23 25         // root= deleten(root,8);

expectation      : 15 10 12 11 20 17 23 25

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger in order to look at what is happening with `root= deleten(root,8);` ?

Comment: It's a tree, so simply deleting a node will delete its children. It's not a problem if it doesn't have children (probably what's happening with 25), but a major problem if it does have children. You need to reorganize the tree after the delete.

Comment: Perhaps you mean else if here, not if: `if (data<root->data)
            root->left = deleten(root->left, data);
        if...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if (data<root->data)
    root->left = deleten(root->left, data);
if (data>root->data)
    root->right = deleten(root->right, data);
else{
    //...
 }
```

If `data` is less than `root->data`, it will delete the `left` side of the tree, **and** the node, since you are using `if` not `else if` to test for the right.

The answer is simple, change to an `else if` instead:

```
if (data<root->data)
    root->left = deleten(root->left, data);
else if (data>root->data)
    root->right = deleten(root->right, data);
else{
    //...
 }
```

Comment: You may also note the `else` following `if (root == NULL) return root;` is superfluous as the function has **returned**. Better to avoid the additional level of indention. You can also recommend [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)